# rake assets:precompile not working on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rake

All of the sudden my server is not able to run assets precompile

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

The error I am getting when running the command with trace is

```
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in    `block in create_shell_runner'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/www/website/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: try bundle update and once again precomplile

Comment: thanks, let me try that once on production and ll let u know..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```